# Displaying error of undefined index on login?

Tags: php

So I am working on a Login Portal and I want the user to not go directly to the link -

> http://localhost/working/HomePage.php

So I added this piece of code in HomePage.php -

```
   session_start();
if($_SESSION["user"] == null)
{
    include 'Login.php';
}
```

I am setting up the session variable in another file AccessControl.php

```
if ($_POST['password'] == "password" and $row["Emp_Password"] == "password")
                {
                    include 'ChangePassword.php';
                }
                elseif ($row["Emp_Password"] == $_POST['password'])
                {
                    $_SESSION["user_pwd"] = $_POST['password'];
                    $_SESSION["user"] = $_SESSION["user_id"];
                    header('Location: HomePage.php');
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Invalid Password!');</script>";
                    include 'Login.php';
                }
```

When I try to access the HomePage.php it is redirecting me to Login page but with a error -

> Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\Working\HomePage.php
>   on line 8

Is their any way that I might get redirected to the homepage and also this error isn't displayed?
Also after I am redirected to `Login.php` I can't Login.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like I have done below and instead of `include` I would recommend `header`. Also use `empty` as stated in the above answer.

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION["user"]))
{
    header("Location:Login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make check as follows:

```
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION["user"])) {
    include 'Login.php';
}
```

Read more about [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).